# How to change part of file via ansible template

Tags: django, ansible

**db_conn.j2:**

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'db_name',
    'USER': 'db_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'db_pass',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432', 
  }
}
```

**main.yml:**

```
tasks:
  - name: Set DB settings
    template: src="/vagrant/ansible/templates/db_settings.j2" dest="{{ proj_dev }}/proj/settings.py"
    tags:
      - template
```

In my task file *settings.py* will be replaced on *db_conn.j2*.
But i need to change only *DATABASES* option in destination file (*settings.py*).

Can i do this via *template*? Or better use *replace*?

Is there other way in *ansible* for set django-settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `template` module will override the complete file. There is no option to only replace a specific section. That's the idea of a template.

You could move the `DATABASES` section out to another file, and then `from database.py import *`, but then of course you'd have the same problem: You need to replace the `DATABASES` section with the `import` rule.

So yes, the `replace` module or the [`lineinfile` module](http://docs.ansible.com/lineinfile_module.html) are generally better suited to replace a section of a file.

But you're lucky, Stouts has created a [django role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/Stouts/django):

You can install it in your project with:

```
ansible-galaxy install Stouts.django
```

Answer (score 1):

The [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html) module introduced in Ansible 2.0 does exactly what you want. It will create and manage a block with special starting and ending marks ("BEGIN/END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK" by default) in your file.